# unable to install pip for python 2.4.3?

Tags: python, pip, windows-7-x64, python-2.4

Currently I am using Windows 7 and Python 2.4.3. Whenever I try to install `pip` using the [get-pip.py](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#do-i-need-to-install-pip) it gives me the following error. Can anyone tell me how to resolve it?

```
C:\Users\nnkashyap\Downloads>python get-pip.py
  File "get-pip.py", line 43
    _b85alphabet = (b"0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
                                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

C:\Users\nnkashyap\Downloads>python
Python 2.4.3 (#69, Mar 29 2006, 17:35:34) [MSC v.1310 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Comment: Python 2.4 is too old. Modern tools require at least 2.7.15 or 3.5+. Whatever tools — pip, setuptools, numpy, anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you got this well, as it is in the [documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/):

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
```

It looks like a corruption problem to me. If that does not work, try this:

Install https://chocolatey.org/ which will handle most pip things for you. It is really easy to install.

You can then type `choco install pip` in a command window. You can also use it for anaconda, python itself, and many other things.

I usually install anaconda first thing instead of "pythong" itself, as the anaconda prompt handles everything else quite well, and for a user without a lot of knowledge, it is quite easy!

Comment: No problem! If it was useful and helped to solve your problem, upvote the question and/or mark it as a solution! @KashyapNeeraj

Comment: I was able to install choco, but I am unable to install pip,numpy or any other python module. [link] (https://imgur.com/a/yU5xlJp). how to resolve this error?

Comment: Have you tried with admin rights? Executing cmd as admin? (Open as administrator) @KashyapNeeraj

Comment: `get-pip`is saved as a .pi, right? try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows) @KashyapNeeraj

Comment: I have added .py and not .pi to the get-pip file.

Comment: That's what I meant sorry, `.py`. It looks quite strange. try `python -m get-pip.py`. Make sure you are following the same steps as in [here](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/install-pip-windows/) @KashyapNeeraj . If not, it might be a python problem. Have you tried uninstalling and installing python again?

Comment: I have installed Python 3.6 and it is working fine right now.

Comment: Okay I'm glad it helped! @KashyapNeeraj

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same error while trying to install pip for python 2.4 via the get-pip.py file (on a windows machine). I tried to delete the python2to3 byte code notation 'b' and further replaced the `with open()` file imports with python 2.4 `file=open()` statements etc., but finally got stuck during calling `main()` with an `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Struct'`(seems like the struct module does not have the Struct() attribute in python 2.4 - couldn't call it from the shell neither!).

However, what finally worked for me was the following:

1) If you don't have setuptools installed yet, get the bootstrap script for the setuptools installation from:
   http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py

=> this one https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap-py24/ez_setup.py.
   from https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/2.0/#python-2-4-and-python-2-5-support
   did not work for me!

2) If you don't have the SSL module installed yet, you have to manually download the 
   setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg file from 
   https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.4/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg

=> Put the .egg file in the same folder as the ez_setup.py file.

3) With python 2.4 activated, go to the directory with 
   the ez_setup.py file, and run `python ez_setup.py` within your console.
   (setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg disappears during the installation process)

4) After having setuptools successfully installed, get pip-1.1 from https://pypi.org/project/pip/1.1/ and unpack it.

5) Go to the pip-1.1 folder and run `python setup.py install` from console.

P.S.: Don't forget to add the /Scripts folder with the pip.exe to your PATH variable!